# Missing dependencies in include during C++ cmake compilation

Tags: c++, onnxruntime

I am new to Cpp and am trying to run the code from [this repo](https://github.com/itsnine/yolov5-onnxruntime) in onnx-runtime.

When I run to ultimately compile the modules

```
cmake --build .
```

I get

```
/yolov5-onnxruntime/include/detector.h:3:10: fatal error: onnxruntime_cxx_api.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>
```

Understanding that the dependencies is missing, how do I find & install the correct dependency automatically with some package manager?

Comment: What is your OS? Not all package managers are cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

The file mentioned in your error message is part of the [ONNX Runtime](https://onnxruntime.ai/). You need to install that package. Installation varies depending on your operating system and other factors and is described in the [installation instructions](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/install/).

On Windows you might simply use:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime
```

but there are other variants, i.e. if you want to use the GPU instead of the CPU.

Note that the software you are trying to compile mentions other dependencies as well, i.e. OpenCV.